# Compute a cosine dissimilarity matrix in R

Tags: r, clustering, similarities, cosine-similarity, cosine-distance

I want to create heatmaps based upon cosine dissimilarity.

I'm using R and have explored several packages, but cannot find a function to generate a standard cosine dissimilarity matrix. The built-in `dist()` function doesn't support cosine distances, also within the package `arules` there is a `dissimilarity()` function, but it only works on binary data.

Can anybody recommend a library?
Or demonstrated how to calculate cosine dissimilarity within R?

Comment: It may be faster to write your own cosine dissimilarity function.

Comment: Cosine is similarity, not dissimilarity. You can, however, turn cosine into euclidean distance of scaled data: d=sqrt(2*(1-cos)).

Comment: Same question over on SO: [Find cosine similarity between two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535234/find-cosine-similarity-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As @Max indicated in the comments (+1) it would be simpler to "write your own" than to spend time looking for it somewhere else. As we know, the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between two vectors $A,B$ of length $n$ is

$$
C = \frac{ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}A_{i} B_{i} }{ \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}^2} \cdot  \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}^2} } $$

which is straightforward to generate in `R`. Let `X` be the matrix where the rows are the values we want to compute the similarity between. Then we can compute the similarity matrix with the following `R` code:

```
cos.sim <- function(ix) 
{
    A = X[ix[1],]
    B = X[ix[2],]
    return( sum(A*B)/sqrt(sum(A^2)*sum(B^2)) )
}   
n <- nrow(X) 
cmb <- expand.grid(i=1:n, j=1:n) 
C <- matrix(apply(cmb,1,cos.sim),n,n)
```

Then the matrix `C` is the cosine similarity matrix and you can pass it to whatever heatmap function you like (the only one I'm familiar with is `image()`).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Actually, I don't want to plot the matrix itself but rather have a distance function for clustering of another heatmap that I have.

Comment: @GregSlodkowicz, OK well perhaps you can pass this matrix to the function you're using. Also, if you've found this answer helpful please consider an upvote (or accepting the answer if you consider it definitive) :)

Comment: Great, thanks to your reply and ttnphns's comment I was able to do what I want. Now I would like to have a different metric when clustering rows than when clustering columns but maybe that's pushing it...

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough points to be able to comment. I just wanted to offer a slightly modified version of Macro's nice answer. Here it is. # ChirazB's version of cos.sim() by Macro
# where S = X %*% t(X)
cos.sim.2 <- function(S,ix)
{ i <- ix[1] j <- ix[2] return( S[i,j]/sqrt(S[i,i]*S[j,j]) )
} #test
X <- matrix(rnorm(20),nrow=5,ncol=4)
S <- X%*%t(X)
n <- nrow(X) idx.arr <- expand.grid(i=1:n, j=1:n) C <- matrix(apply(idx.arr,1,cos.sim,X),n,n)
C2 <- matrix(apply(idx.arr,1,cos.sim.2,S),n,n) I don't like global variable, that's why I included S as a parameter.

Comment: it should be `sqrt(sum(A^2))*sqrt(sum(B^2))` instead of `sqrt(sum(A^2)*sum(B^2))`

Comment: Why? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 30):

---

***Many answers here are computationally inefficient, try this;***

---

***For cosine similarity matrix***

```
Matrix <- as.matrix(DF)
sim <- Matrix / sqrt(rowSums(Matrix * Matrix))
sim <- sim %*% t(sim)
```

***Convert to cosine dissimilarity matrix (distance matrix).***

```
D_sim <- as.dist(1 - sim)
```

Comment: Awesome answer. At least 250x as fast as library(lsa) cosine() when using OpenBLAS and 96 cores.

Comment: I'm glad you appreciate good computational mathematics.

Comment: Way faster than other functions. Thank you Brad.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `cosine` function from the lsa package: 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsa

Comment: Brad's answer is at least 250x as fast as library(lsa) cosine() when using OpenBLAS and 96 cores.

Comment: @Downvoter: What is wrong with my answer???

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, so I don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 6):

#### The following function might be useful when working with matrices, instead of 1-d vectors:

```
# input: row matrices 'ma' and 'mb' (with compatible dimensions)
# output: cosine similarity matrix

cos.sim=function(ma, mb){
  mat=tcrossprod(ma, mb)
  t1=sqrt(apply(ma, 1, crossprod))
  t2=sqrt(apply(mb, 1, crossprod))
  mat / outer(t1,t2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ramping up some of the previous code (from @Macro) on this issue, we can wrap this into a cleaner version in the following:

```
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(c1=rnorm(100),
                              c2=rnorm(100),
                              c3=rnorm(100),
                              c4=rnorm(100),
                              c5=rnorm(100),
                              c6=rnorm(100))))

#df[df > 0] <- 1
#df[df <= 0] <- 0



apply_cosine_similarity <- function(df){
  cos.sim <- function(df, ix) 
  {
    A = df[ix[1],]
    B = df[ix[2],]
    return( sum(A*B)/sqrt(sum(A^2)*sum(B^2)) )
  }   
  n <- nrow(df) 
  cmb <- expand.grid(i=1:n, j=1:n) 
  C <- matrix(apply(cmb,1,function(cmb){ cos.sim(df, cmb) }),n,n)
  C
}
apply_cosine_similarity(df)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it should be sqrt(sum(A^2))*sqrt(sum(B^2)) instead of sqrt(sum(A^2)*sum(B^2))

Comment: Why? Does it make any difference?