# R adjusted cosine similarity

Tags: distance, similarities

I would like to find an effective way to get adjusted cosine similarity for a large matrix  (10k rows).
Apply seems also slow...

Could you please suggest a method?
Maybe based on the approaches suggested here:
[cosine similarity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31565/compute-a-cosine-dissimilarity-matrix-in-r)